# Should api.raml contain the whole API?

Tags: node.js, rest, api-design, raml

I have a simple question about RAML (RESTful Api Modeling language). I wanted to try something new in order to create a documentation for my API (and later test it). The API is written in node.js.

Should I include my whole code in the api.raml file ? Or is it possible to import sub-routes from other .raml files? Are there any good guidelines how to divide .raml files?

e.g. I would like to create a file called `books.raml`. It would include all the routes under `/books`. Then later I want to import it in my `api.raml`, so it would be more like a file that only includes sub-files.

Is it ok? If yes how could I do this and what are the guidelines about where to store this files (in which directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your RAML specification in several files and use the **!include** directive to include files.

For example:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: My API with Types
types: !include myTypes.raml
```

More info about includes [here](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#includes)

Besides that RAML provides libraries: "RAML libraries are used to combine any collection of data type declarations, resource type declarations, trait declarations, and security scheme declarations into modular, externalized, reusable groups"

What and how to use depends on your use case. But I think libraries can provide a better / more meaningful structure.

Check the section about [modularization](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#modularization) for more info.

You can also include routes like you are saying, e.g.:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: bla
/foo/:
  /bar/:
    post:
    get:
/books: !include books.raml
```

But I'm not sure that's a good way of structuring your RAML.

Comment: Ok, this is ok for including traits or types but is it ok to include subroutes e.g. `/accounts: !include accounts.raml` ?

Comment: yes, you can, but I'm not sure that's a good way of structuring your RAML (I updated my answer)